# How to set mouse position in WPF

Tags: wpf, mouse, position

actually there is a way described in http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/wpf/thread/6be8299a-9616-43f4-a72f-799da1193889

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetCursorPos")]   
[return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]   
public static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
```

i would like to define a moveable area for cursor in a custom control. 
using this native function makes cursor flickering.

is there another way to set mouse position which does not bring about flickering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can benefit from the unmanaged [ClipCursor function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648383%28VS.85%29.aspx).